# I want to parse an url to html

Tags: html, node.js, axios

I want to parse an url to html then to use it. For this, I use axios but I get the following error:

```
Request failed with status code 500
```

My code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function parseHtml() {
    const url = 'http://www.ameli.fr/accueil-de-la-ccam/telechargement/index.php';

    let response;
    try {
      response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,

      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
      
    }
    console.log(response.data);
}
```

Any idea please, I try also to use jsdom, htmlparse but I don't get any result

Comment: 500 means server error. Do you have access to the server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That url seems to be sending back a 500 error incorrectly (or it appears so).

You can ignore this error (something you wouldn't normally do!) using the [validateStatus](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) property like so:

```
async function parseHtml() {
    const url = 'http://www.ameli.fr/accueil-de-la-ccam/telechargement/index.php';

    let response;
    try {
        response = await axios({
            url,
            method: 'GET',
            // Ignore failing HTTP status codes
            validateStatus: status => true
        });
        console.log("Response status code:", response.status);
        console.log("Response data:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

This will give you the html data, which you can then parse.